android studio can't read files from folder with
I'm trying to hide some files that are inside a folder from showing in the device's gallery. For that, I created a folder with a dot (.) at the beginning of its name like this:
public File getPathThumbnail() {
    File dir;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) + "/AquaInfo/.FileImages/Thumbnail");
    } else {
        dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/AquaInfo/.FileImages/Thumbnail");
    }

    if (!dir.exists()) {
        boolean success = dir.mkdirs();
        if (!success) {
            dir = null;
        }
    }
    return dir;
}

The issue is that when I try to retrieve a list of files from that specific folder, the list is always empty. If I remove the dot and update my code to use the new folder name (without the dot), I can retrieve the list of all files inside that folder.
The directory has files in it, and I have all the necessary permissions activated.
This is how I try to read the filed from tha directory:
File directory = getPathThumbnail();

        new Thread(() -> {
            while (counter.get() < fichas.length - 3) {
                try {
                    String desiredFileName;
                    if (fichas[counter.get() + 2].equals(getTipo(fichas[counter.get() + 2]))) {
                        desiredFileName = (com.aquarismo.removeSpecialCharacteres.funcRemoveSpecialCharacteres(fichas[counter.get() + 2].replace("\"", "").replace("/", "")) + "--" + fichas[counter.get() + 1] + "--").toLowerCase();
                    } else {
                        desiredFileName = (com.aquarismo.removeSpecialCharacteres.funcRemoveSpecialCharacteres(fichas[counter.get()].replace("\"", "").replace("/", "")) + "--" + fichas[counter.get() + 1] + "--").toLowerCase();
                    }

                    String finalDesiredFileName = desiredFileName;
                    File[] matchingFiles = directory.listFiles((dir, name) -> name.startsWith(finalDesiredFileName));


                    assert matchingFiles != null;
                    if (matchingFiles.length > 0) {
                        Arrays.sort(matchingFiles, Comparator.comparing(File::getName));

                        Arrays.sort(matchingFiles, new DadosFichaTecnica.FileNameComparator());
                        baseDados.setNomeImagemBaseDados(fichas[counter.get() + 1], matchingFiles[matchingFiles.length - 1].getName());
                    }

                    runOnUiThread(() -> {
                        counter.addAndGet(3);
                        progresso.setProgress(counter.get() / 3);
                    });
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2);
                    } catch (Exception ignored) {
                    }
                } catch (Exception error) {
                    runOnUiThread(() -> {
                        counter.addAndGet(3);
                        progresso.setProgress(counter.get() / 3);
                    });
                }

                if (counter.get() >= fichas.length - 3) {
                    restartAplicacao("inicio");
                }
            }
        }).start();

I have also tried to add a .nomedia file to the folder instead of using a dot (.) in its name, but the result is the same. With the file inside the folder, I can't read any of the files inside it. Without the file, I can access the files without any problem.
How can I solve this? I want to hide the files inside the folder from the gallery but still be able to access them from my Android app.
My test device is android 14.
Thanks

"The issue is that when I try to retrieve a list of files from that specific folder, the list is always empty" -- first, you do not have rights to files in Documents/ on Android 11+, except for those that your app created. Second, hiding dot-prefixed files/directories is standard behavior on *nix and Android. "I want to hide the files inside the folder from the gallery but still be able to access them from my Android app" -- do not put them on external storage. Instead, use getFilesDir() on Context and put them on internal storage.

The folder in Documents was created by my app.
